# Using nginx as my server and running a simple flask app. Can i configure nginx to serve flask and non flask urls?

Tags: python, nginx, flask

It seems my site has to be all flask, is there a configuration setting in nginx that will allow me to just throw a temp page up, and is not routed to flask?

Like someone that has no flask knowledge, they just want to put up a simple page. Yes, it can be all done under flask, just wondering does it have to be? Is it all or none? Everything routes to flask now.

Summary: Can i have a flask and a non flask site running at the same time? Or maybe I can configure flask to point to a sandbox directory?

Pondering this. thanks

[image]
[image]

Latest site-available changes - not finding this directory:

[image]

Comment: Short answer yes, you can route requests to different endpoints in NGINX or just serve content. You might want to include some of your nginx configuration etc in your question.

Comment: Good idea.  I'm using this example:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04

Posted the main files.

Comment: Do you want to have the two apps under the same domain? Do you want to have different locations for each app. I would use a NGINX proxy configuration. Can share a example if you want.

Comment: hi timo, think i will try pvilas suggestion. And come back to you if does not work. Basically a directory on my server that has no clue about Flask. Like it does not exist.

Comment: hi Tim, i'm up for it. What's your suggestion?   Posted the latest config setup [black|white] screen. Still not working. "File not found."

A home page which is working fine for Flask, and then another directory (calling it "maps" for now) that has zero connections to Flask. 

100% independent.  thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, you want nginx to handle some resources directly.

You need a *static route*, using **root**, like

```
location /static {
            root /home/ubuntu/example/example;
    }
```

and let the others locations be handled by the proxy.

I have a nginx/uwsgi/flask [configuration tutorial](http://pvilas.com/2019/08/Instalar-flask-como-servicios.html) but unfortunately its only in spanish.

Comment: HI, ran site through Google translate. It looks like almost like a perfect English translation.  Will give it a try and report back.  thanks!  :-)

I love that nginx origins are Russian. They are so hardcore!  Even in America, when we work with coders, in the end we say, those Russians, they are amazing!

Run it by that Russian kid down the hall! Before we go live.

 I'm sure they could get Photoshop to run off a 10 MB USB stick, if they wanted 2.  LOL

Comment: I added the static route. And a directory called maps. Flask works fine for my default home page, but still not finding this directory.  Added code screenshot above.  

/var/www/html/maps/   & /var/www/html/maps   comes back with: 
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

No editing needed. Just put anything you want to serve in static, and have that in the url.

Understanding now static files can be anything.

Guess was not clear on what "static" meant. And can edit that in the config file if want to have a clean url.